# how to pass parameters to url

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session, parameters

I'm trying to pass parameters to a URL and get them into a controller function: 
in an anchor `onclick` I passed the value to a javascript function.

This is the onclick anchor:

```
<a href="" onclick="change_lang('<?=base_url()?>home/change_lang','en')">English</a>
```

and this is the javascript function:

```
function change_lang(page,str)
{
  var url=page;
  var params='?lang='+str;

  makerequest_sp(url, params);
}
```

and this is the controller function:

```
public function change_lang()
{
  $lang=$this->input->Get('lang');

  if(!isset($lang))
  {
    $this->session->set_userdata('lang',"en"); 
  }
  else
  {
    $this->session->set_userdata('lang',$lang); 
  }

  redirect(base_url());
}
```

and this makerequest_sp function:

```
  function makerequest_sp(serverPage, params, objID)
{ 
    var xmlhttp_sp = getXMLHttp();
    //set url
    var url = serverPage;

    //set xml method to POST
    xmlhttp_sp.open("POST", url, true);
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xmlhttp_sp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp_sp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp_sp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlhttp_sp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.

        if(xmlhttp_sp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp_sp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(objID).innerHTML = xmlhttp_sp.responseText;
        }
    }
    //send parameters
    xmlhttp_sp.send(params);    

}
```

But I cant access to passed parameters.

Comment: How do you get from `makerequest_sp` to the `change_lang` function in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an AJAX request. I'm guessing you're wondering why the `redirect` doesn't make the browser redirect?

This is because the AJAX request is getting the redirect, not the page.

Instead of sending a redirect header you can pass back the URL the page should redirect to, or in case you *know* the URL already you can just redirect right away:

```
makerequest_sp(/* .. */).done(function () {
    document.location.href = url;
});

// using Promise assumption for ajax request
```